# Bus seat reservation algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm working on bus ticket reservation system. I have a problem in the booking module.

Say we have bus a route starts from "A" to "D" via "B" & "C"

The bus starts from "A" then reach "B", then "C" and final destination is "D".

Assume some one is reserving seat no "1" for "B" to "C", this seat no should not be available for the person who is searching for a seat to travel from "A" to "D" or "B" to "D" but the same seat should be available for "A" to "B" or "C" to "D"

Example in Summary

Seat No 1 is Reserved for "B" to "C"

- Seat No 1 should not be available for "A"-"D"
- Seat No 1 should not be available for "B"-"D"
- Seat No 1 should not be available for "B"-"C"
- Seat No 1 should be available for "A" to "B"
- Seat No 1 should be available for "C" to "D"

Could you please if there is already an algorithm or dotnet c# code to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to have two variables 1)start 2) stop.  Then you need to compare the seat start and stop with the ticket start and stop.  There is no algorithm, just simple comparison of two objects.  I would create a class object for Route that contains a string start and string end.  In the class a method called compare that compares two Routes (start and end).  Then Seat one will be a List<Route> with A(start) B(end) and B(start) C(end).  Then you can have tickets that are Routes with start and end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "homework" answer is the one that explains the solution best:

Write down your bus stops on a piece of paper

```
A ---- B ---- C ---- D ---- E ---- F
```

Then try this

1. Put your left finger on `A` then with your right finger, touch each letter consecutively (`B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`) and ask your self is that seat available for this trip (until you get to `F`).
2. Then move your left finger `B` then with your right finger, touch each letter consecutively (`C`, `D`, `E`, `F`) and ask your self is that seat available for this trip (until you get to `F`).
3. Then move your left finger `C` then with your right finger, touch each letter consecutively (`D`, `E`, `F`) and ask your self is that seat available for this trip (until you get to `F`).
4. you get the idea...

Do you see whats happening here? you are slowly checking each combination. So whats the significance of your 2 fingers you may ask? well they can be thought of as 2 indexes in a list of stops...

So how do we iterate a list and use 2 indexes you may ask... just use 2 `for`  loops, one inside the other

```
for(var leftFingerIndex = 0; leftFingerIndex < NumberOfStops; leftFingerIndex++)
    for(var rightFingerIndex = leftFingerIndex + 1; rightFingerIndex< NumberOfStops; rightFingerIndex++)
       // if the your right finger is ever at bus stop were your seat is booked
       // then the trip from your left finger to the right + 1 is invalid, 
       // and all subsequent right finger indexes
```

Hopefully this will give you the tools and help needed to solve the problem.

Good luck